# PHP - Check Date Range

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a table on database called `period`. The fields in this table are: `code | name | status | open_date | close_date`. The date format is `Y/m/d`.

This is what I want: if today's date is out of date range in the database, the site won't display a form and a table column.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$sql5 = "select close_date from period"
         . " where status='1'";
$result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql5);
if (!$result5) {
    die("<h3>SQL Error</h3>" . $sql5);
}
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5);

$date = date("Y/m/d");
?>

<?php
if($date >= $row3['open_date'] && $date <= $row5['close_date']) {
?>
<form action="manageInputPerwalian.php" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
                <td>MK Code:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mkCode"/></td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
                <td>KP:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kp"/></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php } ?>


<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>MK CODE</th>
            <th>MK NAME</th>
            <th>CLASS</th>
            <?php if($date >= $row3['open_date'] && $date <= $row5['close_date']) { ?>
                <th>CANCEL</th>
            <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But, either today's date is out of range or in the range, the form and the table column won't show up. What's wrong? Please explain your answer. Thanks

Comment: Try this:  `if(strtotime($date) >= strtotime($row3['open_date']) && strtotime($date) <= strtotime($row5['close_date']))`

Comment: @FrayneKonok It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the dates to timestamp and compare, as,

```
$openDateStr = strtotime($row3['open_date']);
$closeDateStr = strtotime($row5['close_date']);
$todayStr = strtotime(date("Y/m/d"));
//compare
if($todayStr >= $openDateStr && $todayStr <= $closeDateStr) {
..
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok true, might be i was a bit late while typing the answer.. :) you  could add your answer, if you added it in comment before i answered.. in that case i'll delete mine.. :)

Comment: It's working. I don't know that I can use operator to string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everything you did right. Some small mistakes only.

1. There is no $row3 variable. Only $row5 only. So change row3 to row5.
2. In select query you selected only close_date. you need to select open_date also.
3. Next use strtotime() functions to compare.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to type the open_date query here, but I already have it in my actual code, and it's stored in var $row3. Thanks. Maybe you want to edit my question by adding the number 1 & 2 from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really worng with your code. Just a few miner fixes. `$row3` should probably be `$row5` in your code.

```
// Create a DateTime object
$now = new DateTime();

$stmt = "select close_date
from period
where status='1'
";

$result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql5);

if (!$result5) {
    die("<h3>SQL Error</h3>" . $sql5);
}
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5);

$date = date("Y/m/d");
```

And then, your HTML

```
<!-- Note that you were using $row3 here -->
<?php if ($now->format('Y-m-d') >= $row5['open_date'] && $now->format('Y-m-d') <= $row5['close_date']): ?>
<form action="manageInputPerwalian.php" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
                <td>MK Code:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mkCode"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KP:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="kp"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php èndif; ?>


<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>MK CODE</th>
            <th>MK NAME</th>
            <th>CLASS</th>
            <?php if ($now->format('Y-m-d') >= $row5['open_date'] && $now->format('Y-m-d') <= $row5['close_date']): ?>
                <th>CANCEL</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```